# Fill missing rows in a python pandas dataframe with repetitive pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fix missing rows in a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.2, 3.4], [2, 4.5, 6.7], [3, 1.3, 2.5], [4, 5.6, 7.3],
               [1, 3.4, 5.8], [2, 5.7, 8.9], [4, 2.4, 2.6], [1, 6.7, 8.4],
               [3, 6.9, 4.2], [4, 4.2, 1.2]], columns = ['#', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

The above code give me a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Out[10]: 
   #  foo  bar
0  1  1.2  3.4
1  2  4.5  6.7
2  3  1.3  2.5
3  4  5.6  7.3
4  1  3.4  5.8
5  2  5.7  8.9
6  4  2.4  2.6
7  1  6.7  8.4
8  3  6.9  4.2
9  4  4.2  1.2
```

As you probably noticed, the values in the `'#'` column are in a repetitive pattern as `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...` but with some missing values (for this instance, `3` before row 6 and `2` before row 8).  **My question is:  Is there any built in method (function) in pandas to fill the missing rows in this dataframe according to the repetitive pattern of `'#'` column?** The values in the other columns of the filling rows can be `NaN`, or the interpolation\extrapolation\average of the values before and\or after the filling rows.  In the other words, what I want is like this:

```
Out[16]: 
    #  foo  bar
0   1  1.2  3.4
1   2  4.5  6.7
2   3  1.3  2.5
3   4  5.6  7.3
4   1  3.4  5.8
5   2  5.7  8.9
6   3  NaN  NaN
7   4  2.4  2.6
8   1  6.7  8.4
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  3  6.9  4.2
11  4  4.2  1.2
```

I tried to set the `'#'` column as the index of the dataframe and reindex it with regular pattern without missing values.  But the problem is the `pd.reindex` doesn't work with duplicate values.  I know I can always go traditional way by iterating in a loop from line to line to fix it but I am afraid this would be time consuming if working with large size data.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a hint on this.

Comment: Can there be more than one consecutive missing value? (if true, there is the issue that there could be infinitely many missing cycles between any two rows)

Comment: There could be more than 1 consecutive missing value..  I actually work with relative large data sets and usually there is one line missing data but the consecutive multiple lines missing data could happen.  @jezrael provided good solutions which work with multiple missing lines too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create groups some way - here is used difference of values `#` and comparing with `>1` by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html), then is used [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['#'].diff().lt(1).cumsum())
         .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('#').reindex(range(1, 5)))
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
    #  foo  bar
0   1  1.2  3.4
1   2  4.5  6.7
2   3  1.3  2.5
3   4  5.6  7.3
4   1  3.4  5.8
5   2  5.7  8.9
6   3  NaN  NaN
7   4  2.4  2.6
8   1  6.7  8.4
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  3  6.9  4.2
11  4  4.2  1.2
```

Another idea is create `MultiIndex` and reshape by `unstack` and `stack`:

```
df = (df.set_index(['#', df['#'].diff().lt(1).cumsum()])
       .unstack()
       .reindex(np.arange(4)+1)
       .stack(dropna=False)
       .sort_index(level=1)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
    #  foo  bar
0   1  1.2  3.4
1   2  4.5  6.7
2   3  1.3  2.5
3   4  5.6  7.3
4   1  3.4  5.8
5   2  5.7  8.9
6   3  NaN  NaN
7   4  2.4  2.6
8   1  6.7  8.4
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  3  6.9  4.2
11  4  4.2  1.2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can mark each group of `1,2,3,4` with `eq` and `cumsum`.

Then we `groupby` on these groups and use `reindex` and finally `concat` them back together.

```
s = df['#'].eq(4).shift().cumsum().bfill()

pd.concat(
    [d.set_index('#').reindex(np.arange(4)+1) for _, d in df.groupby(s)]
).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    #  foo  bar
0   1  1.2  3.4
1   2  4.5  6.7
2   3  1.3  2.5
3   4  5.6  7.3
4   1  3.4  5.8
5   2  5.7  8.9
6   3  NaN  NaN
7   4  2.4  2.6
8   1  6.7  8.4
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  3  6.9  4.2
11  4  4.2  1.2
```

---

**Note**: if you would have a `4` as missing value in your `#` column, this method would fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @jezrael sans the `reindex` and `sort_index`:

```
df['rep'] = df['#'].diff().le(0).cumsum()

(df.set_index(['rep','#'])
   .unstack('#')
   .stack('#', dropna=False)
   .reset_index('#')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
    #  foo  bar
0   1  1.2  3.4
1   2  4.5  6.7
2   3  1.3  2.5
3   4  5.6  7.3
4   1  3.4  5.8
5   2  5.7  8.9
6   3  NaN  NaN
7   4  2.4  2.6
8   1  6.7  8.4
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  3  6.9  4.2
11  4  4.2  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) to expose the missing values :

```
#  pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

 # cumsum creates identifiers for the groups in `#`
(df.assign(counter = df['#'].eq(1).cumsum())
   .complete('#', 'counter')
    # sorting can be ignored, if order is not important
   .sort_values('counter', ignore_index = True)
   .drop(columns='counter'))

    #  foo  bar
0   1  1.2  3.4
1   2  4.5  6.7
2   3  1.3  2.5
3   4  5.6  7.3
4   1  3.4  5.8
5   2  5.7  8.9
6   3  NaN  NaN
7   4  2.4  2.6
8   1  6.7  8.4
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  3  6.9  4.2
11  4  4.2  1.2
```