# how to copy and paste values until specific column ends in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill nans with previous values so wondering how to copy and paste values until single column ends.

Here is the data I've got

```
Time                indicator   Value
2021-03-01 11:00     602500     1015.31
2021-05-01 8:00      602500     1017.61
2021-05-01 5:00      307001     3485.2
NaN                  307001     3335.5
NaN                  307002     3357.3
...                  ...        ...
NaN                  307005     3337.5

3045 rows * 3 columns
```

I want to fill NaNs in Time with the previous values in the column.
I 've tried to use ffill method but it only fill with single previous values.

```
df['Time'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

I want to replace NaNs with all the previous values until the column ends.

```
The desired output is below
Time                indicator   Value
2021-03-01 11:00     602500     1015.31
2021-05-01 8:00      602500     1017.61
2021-05-01 5:00      307001     3485.2
2021-03-01 11:00     307001     3335.5
2021-05-01 8:00      307002     3357.3
...                  ...        ...
2021-05-01 5:00      307005     3337.5
```

Comment: this thread might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094233/fill-missing-rows-in-a-python-pandas-dataframe-with-repetitive-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a mapping to `groupby()` like so:

```
df.groupby(df.index % df.Time.isna().idxmax()).ffill()
```

Note here that `df.Time.isna().idxmax()` is getting the index of the first `NaN` value in the `Time` column so that you know how many values to modulus the index by for grouping.

Comment: what if I don't know how many values I've got?

Comment: I get attribute error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'idxmax'

Comment: Are you calling `idxmax` or `idxmax()`? It's a method not an attribute...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to repeat that same loop of three dates each time?  Someone can code-golf it eventually, but this should do what you're looking for:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
##  pip3 install pandas
##  python3 -m install pandas

import pandas as pd

timestamp = pd ._libs .tslibs .timestamps .Timestamp
NaN = pd ._libs .tslibs .nattype .NaTType

'''  or you could
import numpy as np
NaN = np .nan
'''

df = pd .DataFrame( [
    [ pd .to_datetime('2021-03-01 11:00'), 602500, 1015.31 ],
    [ pd .to_datetime('2021-05-01 8:00'),  602500,  1017.61 ],
    [ pd .to_datetime('2021-05-01 5:00'),  307001,  3485.2 ],
    [ NaN,  307001,  3335.5 ],
    [ NaN,  307002,  3357.3 ],
    [ NaN,  307005,  3337.5 ],
],  columns = [ 'Time', 'Indicator', 'Value' ]  )

##  above was just for testing

for row in range( len( df .index ) ):
    entrytype = type( df .loc[ row, 'Time'] )
    if entrytype != str and entrytype != timestamp:  ##  if it's not a datetime value
        df .loc[ row, 'Time'] = df .loc[ row -3, 'Time']  ##  replace with 3 rows back

print( df )
```

> Time  Indicator    Value
> 0  2021-03-01 11:00:00     602500  1015.31
> 1  2021-05-01 08:00:00     602500  1017.61
> 2  2021-05-01 05:00:00     307001  3485.20
> 3  2021-03-01 11:00:00     307001  3335.50
> 4  2021-05-01 08:00:00     307002  3357.30
> 5  2021-05-01 05:00:00     307005  3337.50